# DAX Date Range Syntax - Count one Row More Than Once?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tabular, dax

I'm working with a SQL 2014 tabular model and I want to create a measure for count based on a date range.

My fact table will have a start and ending date range which can span multiple months.  I want the user to be able to select a date range to get a count of records.  The catch is that each month a record spans needs to be captured as separate in the count.

For example:  Record 1 - 1/1/2014 - 8/21/2014.  If the user selects a date range of 3/1 to 5/1, I want the count to return as 3 (March, April and May).  If the user selects 6/4/ - 6/4, I want the count to return as 1.

Is there a way I can do this with DAX or should I go the route of creating a record for each month?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not exactly clear; but assuming that your `StartDate` and `EndDate` are in the same row - you are in effect, looking to count the number of month between these 2 dates and that can be achieved as follows;

```
=(YEAR([EndDate])-YEAR([StartDate]))*12+MONTH([EndDate])-MONTH([StartDate])
```

Your measure would then `SUM()` the results of this calculated column.